# Integration Proofs

Tags: definite-integrals

Prove

Show that for $x\geq 1$

$\displaystyle\left|\int_1^x \frac {\sin(t)}{t} dt\right|$ $ \leq \ln(x)  $

Attempt:

$\displaystyle\left|\int_1^x \frac {\sin(t)}{t} dt\right|$ $   $ $ \leq  $ $\displaystyle\int_1^x$ $\left| \dfrac {\sin(t)}{t}\right| dt$

Comment: Note that this estimate is bad when $x>\pi$. The integral takes its largest value $0.905854$ at $x=\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\int_{1}^{x}\lvert\frac{\sin(t)}{t}\rvert dt\le\int_{1}^{x}\frac{1}{t}dt$. Now integrate.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. What do you know about the bounds of $\sin(t)$?

Answer (score 0):

In fact,
$$
\biggl|\int_{1}^{x}\dfrac{\sin t}{t}dt\biggr| \leq \int_{1}^{x}\biggl|\dfrac{\sin t}{t}\biggr|dt = \int_{1}^{x}\dfrac{|\sin t|}{|t|}dt = \int_{1}^{x}\dfrac{|\sin t|}{t}dt \leq \int_{1}^{x}\dfrac{dt}{t} = \ln x
$$
Note that $|\sin x| \leq 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.